# Cannot start Visual Studio 2015 w 10 performance analysis, giving error that .etl files not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Cannot start Visual Studio 2015 w 10 performance analysis, giving error that .etl files not found...so unable to delete .etl files

[image]

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the error

Comment: Following is the error :- Error deleting Q:\SwSolution\sld180402.etl and Q:\SwSolution\sld180402.kernel.etl output files: Could not find a part of the path 'Q:\SwSolution\sld180402.etl

Comment: do you run VS as admin?

Comment: no..my code is in virtual drives ..if i run vs as an admin virtual drives are not visible

Comment: That's the problem. You need to open your code from a folder that is accessible from the admin account. (By the way, the same thing applies when you use the "subst" command to create directory shortcuts.)

Comment: its worked...run VS as an admin and make the virtual drive substitute using subst command..thanks